# Why can't there be a problem both in P and NPC

Tags: computational-complexity

In [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aComplexity_classes.svg) illustration, P and NPC are two disjoint set.

We know that NPC is non-empty. If P $\cap$ NPC $=\varnothing$, then there are elements in NP which are not in P. Doesn't this imply that P $\neq$ NP?

Comment: You're right that the illustration you link to assumes that P ≠ NP.  Note that on the P versus NP Wikipedia page, it has the caption "Diagram of complexity classes provided that P ≠ NP."

Answer (score 0):

If there is even a single NPC problem in P, then P = NP. NPC problems are defined to be the hardest problems in NP in a suitable sense: every other NP problem reduces to them in polynomial time.